# Where can $PATH be defined for non-login shell on Red Hat

Tags: redhat, path, bashrc

I need to add a directory to the path for non-login shells on a Red Hat Server.

```
ssh user@server echo \$PATH
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

How can I add a directory to this path.  I tried putting `export PATH=$PATH:/my/path`
in `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` but in both cases `ssh user@server echo \$PATH` gives the same result as above. So where is that magic place to add `my/path` to `$PATH` for non-login shells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question since I haven't tested it on redhat, but for ubuntu users check out /etc/environment